# MySQL.connector module not found

Tags: python, mysql, linux

I have some python code that is attempting to utilize mysql.connector
I have installed and uninstalled it in a plethora of ways, yet I still get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "instructionreader.py", line 3, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
ImportError: No module named mysql.connector
```

and have verified it exists via

```
pi@raspberrypi:/var/www/html $ python
Python 2.7.16 (default, Oct 10 2019, 22:02:15) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mysql.connector
>>>
```

What might be the issue here?

Comment: Looks like your code is using different version of python but your module installed is for different version.

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved 
Looks like your code is using different version of python but your module installed is for different version. was correct